# Bookmark in Word leads to Reviewing Pane

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks

I made bookmarks in a Word document, and it works perfectly to me. But when I sent the document to another one, he said that when he clicks *"go to"* a bookmark, as well as when he clicks a hyperlink that leads to a bookmark, he is instead being redirected to *"Reviewing Pane"* (which is not where I made the bookmarks). What may be the reason, and how can he fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could arise from incompatibility between various Microsoft Word versions.
It's possible that the recipient is making use of a more recent version of Word with the "Reviewing Pane" option enabled, which is interfering with the bookmarks and hyperlinks.

The recipient can try turning off Word's "Reviewing Pane" feature to fix the problem:

- Select the "View" tab from the ribbon.
- In the "Show" section, uncheck "Reviewing Pane."

If that doesn't work, the recipient can also try changing the hyperlinks to refer directly to the relevant page number or part in the document rather than to a bookmark, as this approach is less likely to encounter compatibility problems.